# Get POST variables in Symfony before Filters

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.1, symfony-2.3

I have set up event listener for this as said in the [tutorial here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html)

but i need to get access to the POST variables which i seems not possible.
I get empty array in $requestData , please help

```
class TokenListener  {

    public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event) {

        $requestData = $event->getRequest()->request->all(); 

}
```

Comment: In the documentation they say to use the  `$event->getRequest()->query` and not `$event->getRequest()->request` did you tried it?

Comment: `request->query` is `$_GET` rather than the `$_POST`.

Comment: I want to get all the post variables in an array

Comment: Try to subscribe on kernel.request

Comment: This works fine to me, can you post your service definition please? Can you also dump `$event->getRequest()->getMethod()` in your listener to be sure you use a POST request?